# Extend @Url.Action to pass multiple actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm attempting to use @Url.Action to pass multiple parameters through the URL in such a way I can read in the extra parameters using the RouteAttribute

```
<li><a class="survey-button" href="
@Url.Action("Survey",(Model.SurveyID).ToString(),"Page"(Model.PageNumber).ToString())
">Previous</a></li>

//localhost:8080/Survey/1/Page/1
[Route("Survey/{surveyID}/Page/{pageNumber}")]
public ActionResult Page(int surveyID, int pageNumber)
{
...
```

I realize I can pass these via a query string, but for cleanliness reasons this is not preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your parameters in a `RouteValueDictionary` or an anonymous object (easier). I am assuming that your controller name is `SurveyController`.

```
@Url.Action("Page", "Survey", new {surveyId = Model.SurveyId, pageNumber = Model.PageNumber})
```

Comment: if the OP's controller name is `SurveyController` then your syntax is incorrect for `Url.Action`.. you need to swap `"Page"` with `"Survey"`.. the **actionName** comes before the **controllerName**

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid You're right, my mistake. Fixed. I'm spoiled by intellisense.

Comment: @DPac, if I pass in the code snippet you supplied above(@Url.Action("Page", "Survey", new {surveyId = Model.SurveyID, pageNumber = Model.SurveyPageNumber})), I get a url with a query string (/Page/1?surveyId=1), which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Intellisense tends to have that affect on everyone haha.

Comment: @msio can you be clear on what you want your url to look like?

Comment: @msio - That is because your URL is being generated from a route that is *not* the one in your question. The first route that matches the route values passed in `Url.Action` always wins. Best guess is that you have failed to enable attribute routing by calling `routes.MapMvcRouteAttributes()` before you register your other routes, but you could also have another route with route values that match that could also be the reason.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid //localhost:8080/Survey/1/Page/1

Comment: @NightOwl888 I have called routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); in my RouteConfig class. Can you provide the code snippet you would use to hypothetically create the following URL given a controller of Survey and an Action of Page:  //localhost:8080/Survey/1/Page/1?

Comment: I modified my RouteConfig by an additional routes.MapRoute and now the @Url.Action HTML helper is generating the correct URL. Thank you all for your help!